# Using present tense with would?

Tags: exam-questions

> The animals would hunt for food and bring it to the lion and the lion in turn would distribute the food to all.

Is it all right to use *bring* with *would* which is a past tense form of *will* or it should be changed to *brought* ? Also someone suggested to use *amongst* in last part of sentence i.e. *distribute the food amongst all*  Is it required or *to* is fine here ?

Answer (score 1):

"Bring" is fine because you are really saying this:

> "The animals would hunt for food and **would bring** it to the lion,
>   **who**, in turn, would distribute the food to all."

I've made corrections above as you should probably have a "who" and some commas; however, this is not necessary; you can say it the way you have written it, but you should probably add a comma after the second "lion" and then after "turn". Also, you could use "amongst" or "among", but "to" is fine.